# In JQuery check if window.open streamed file contents to a new window sucessfully

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user clicks on a document icon, I am opening/streaming the document in a new window using window.open.  The call returns windowObjectReference which gives me access to the child window.  However if the child window failed to open a document such as a pdf in a pdf viewer because it was not installed on the local machine, how can I determine that the document failed to open in a suitable viewer such as PDF Viewer or Word etc.  The code below shows the javascript function I am using.

```
function LoadDocument(id) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: 'Dashboard/GetDocument',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: { "id": id },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                doc = data;
                if (data !== undefined) {
                    if (doc.Result == true) {

                        var windowObjectReference = window.open("data:" + doc.ContentType + ";base64, " + doc.Document, '', 'height=650,width=840,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1');

                         if (windowObjectReference  === undefined) {
                            var a = document.createElement("a");
                            a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64," + doc.Document;
                            a.download = doc.Filename;
                            document.body.appendChild(a);
                            a.click();
                        }

                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Unable to obtain the document from the database.');
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Unable to load the document.');
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert("Error occurred while loading the avatar image. "
                    + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The windowObjectReference returns an object instance even when a document fails to load in a new window.  Is there some other way to check if the window.open method failed?

Comment: why don't you check for the file before opening the window?

Comment: the file to view inthe is a base64string which will be streamed to the new window. if a blank window opens using the window.open function, is there a way to check the return value to determine if the window is blank?

Comment: In the end I checked if the window is closed, then opened the save as dialog box...if (windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
                    // to do set timer for 3 seconds
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64," + doc.Document;
                    a.download = doc.Filename;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                }